# Dividing by greater number

Tags: calculus, inequality

My question is very simple (I think so), but I have a trouble to get the precise understanding of the following question.

Let's take into consideration the following function:
$$f(n,a,s_1,s_2,...s_n)=\frac{1}{n(1+s_1)}+\frac{1}{n(1+s_2)^2}+...+\frac{1}{n(1+s_n)^n}-\left(\frac{a}{n(1+s_2)^2}+\frac{2a}{n(1+s_3)^3}+...\frac{(n-1)a}{n(1+s_n)^n}\right)-\frac{1}{(1+s_n)^n},$$
where $n$ is integer, $a\in(0,1), s_i\in(0,1), i=1, 2,...,n$ and $s_1<s_2<...<s_n$. The function $f$ attains positive, negative as well as zero values.

If we replace all $s_i$'s  $(i=1,...,n-1)$ by $s_n$ is it correct to write the following relationship (note: $s_1<...<s_n$)
$$\frac{1}{n(1+s_1)}+\frac{1}{n(1+s_2)^2}+...+\frac{1}{n(1+s_n)^n}-\left(\frac{a}{n(1+s_2)^2}+\frac{2a}{n(1+s_3)^3}+\frac{(n-1)a}{n(1+s_n)^n}\right)-\frac{1}{(1+s_n)^n}>\frac{1}{n(1+s_n)}+\frac{1}{n(1+s_n)^2}+...+\frac{1}{n(1+s_n)^n}-\left(\frac{a}{n(1+s_n)^2}+\frac{2a}{n(1+s_n)^3}+...\frac{(n-1)a}{n(1+s_n)^n}\right)-\frac{1}{(1+s_n)^n}.$$

Comment: replacing with $s_n$ will make all the terms smaller but some are added but some are subtracted so you have no idea how they compare.  If you replace all the terms you add with $s_n$ and all the terms you subtract with $s_1$ you will get something definitely smaller.  But it might not be the value you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to check that the inequality you asking is equivalent to

$$g(n,a,s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n (1-(i-1)a)\left(\frac{1}{(1+s_i)^i}-\frac{1}{(1+s_n)^i}\right)>0.$$

This may be wrong for $a$ close to 1. For instance, MathCad calculates $g(4,0.99,0.05,0.1,0.15,0.9)\simeq –0.07$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me continue the work you have done.

Comment: If we assume that $1-(n-1)a>0$, therefore this inequality holds for every $i's$. From another side, we have that $\frac{1}{(1+s_i)^i}-\frac{1}{(1+s_n)^i}>0$ for every $i=1,...,n-1$, therefore the function $g(n,a,s_1,....,s_n)>0$. Do you agree?

Comment: @David Right.  ...

Comment: Please note, that we can write the function $g()$ in the following way: $g(n,a,s_1,s_2,...,s_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1-(i-1a)}{n}\left (\frac{1}{(1+s_i)^i}-\frac{1}{(1+s_n)^i}\right)$